# при ajax запросе PHP не видет созданых мною куков

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

При входе в систему я записываю куки данны способом

```
                    if (!$_COOKIE['email'] AND !$_COOKIE['project']) {
                        setcookie('email', $getParametrs['email'], time() + 3600);
                        setcookie('project', $getParametrs['caseid'], time() + 3600);
                    }
```

Далее я делаю Ajax запрос, у меня есть метод `getAllUserDataByEmail`

```
if($_COOKIE['email']) {
            try {
                // if email is not set then get email by logged in WP user
                $where = implode(' OR ', [
                    CrmConnector::apiBuildCondition('contact', 'primaryEmail',
                        '=',
                        $_COOKIE['email']),
                    CrmConnector::apiBuildCondition('contact', 'secondaryEmail',
                        '=', $_COOKIE['email']),
                ]);
                $crmContact = CrmConnector::apiQueryRecords('contact', $where);
                return $crmContact;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->activeProject = null;
            }
            return false;

        }
```

В куках email имеется, если просто сделать var_dump($_COOKIE), также есть email, но во время ajax запрос, не видет `$_COOKIE['email']`, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить пятый параметр  '/' в функцию вот так  ``setcookie('email', $getParametrs['email'], time() + 3600,'/');`` Это должно сказать php что кука предназначена на весь сайт

Comment: @AndrewMedvedev спасибо большое! Это помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление пятого параметра path ('/' - любой путь на сервере) в setcookie , который указывает браузеру из какой директории будут доступны cookie, решает данный вопрос.
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php